# If a player rolls 3 consecutive 6s and on second six landed on another player’s token can they take a turn?

Tags: untagged

After landing on another player’s token on second 6 when dice rolled third time (because previous turn was 6)

If a player rolls a 6 on third roll it cannot move further because of rolling three sixes. However, as they landed on another player's token on second six they gained an extra turn.

Does a player get another turn after third six?

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr  On the the third roll of a 6 the players turn immediately ends.

As Ludo is a traditional game that is many 1000's years old its hard to find an official rules source.

The Wikipedia article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludo_(board_game))  says-

> When a 6 is rolled, the player may choose to advance a token already
>   in play, or may enter another staged token to its starting square.
>   Rolling a 6 earns the player an additional or "bonus" roll in that
>   turn. If the bonus roll results in a 6 again, the player earns an
>   additional bonus roll. If the third roll is also a 6, the player may
>   not move and the turn immediately passes to the next player.

Rolling the 3rd 6 means the players turn immediately ends. I couldn't find anything in any other rules to contradict that.

Wikipedia also talks about different variants-

> To speed the game up, extra turns or bonus moves can be awarded for
>   capturing a piece or getting a piece home; these may grant passage
>   past a block.

As Ludo is such as old game it is not not surprising there are going to be many different variations including this rule which you used in your example. However the outcome is the same.

Here are two examples
1) Player rolls a 6.  They take an action. They roll again.
Player rolls a 6.  They take an action. They roll again.
Player rolls a 6.  There turn immediately ends.

2) Player rolls a 6.  They take an action. They roll again.
Player rolls any 6 and lands on an opponents piece.  They take an action. They roll again.
Player rolls a 6.  There turn immediately ends.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I learned that Ludo is a heavily customised game right now with many variations.

Comment: @sanjay  I see your new to stack exchange.  If your happy with the answer then please 'accept' the answer my selecting the tick by it.  This helps show other users if a question has been answered or not.